# How to insert text file to database table phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I have a `batchcode.txt` which contains list of batch code.

```
645863
302422
430307
821773
599738
671768
732159
```

and so on

I have a table in my database which is called `batchcode` with fields `'id'`,`'batchcode'`.

**My problem is it wont insert my text file into my table called `batchcode`**. I already did the import and select table but nothing works...

I need some help can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?
$host= "localhost"; //These 7 lines to connect to database
$user= "root";
$pass= "";
$db="database_name";

$connect= mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
if (!$connect)die ("Cannot connect!");
mysql_select_db($db, $connect);

$file = fopen("batchcode.txt","r");  // Open the txt file for reading

while(! feof($file))
{
$line = fgets($file);
$sql = "INSERT INTO batchcode( batchcode ) VALUES ('$line')"; //Insert every read line from txt to mysql database
mysql_query($sql);
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

Note: Specify your database name in `$db="database_name";` create table named `batchcode`, create columns named `id` and `batchcode` (`id`column should have `AUTO_INCREMENT` property).

Comment: Check you database name, table name and column names.

Answer (score 1):

You have to split txt file by new line

```
$file = fopen("batchcode.txt","r");

$file = explode("\n", $file);

foreach ($file as $value){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO batchcode( batchcode ) VALUES ('$value')";
}
```